# Is there a way for a text object (curve) to contain more than one font size?

Tags: python, bezier-curves, text-object

I have a javascript rich text editor (like the one I write in right now).

I have to take the rich text and write it some how with a single text object in blender (through python script). It will contain strong text, colours, and different font sizes.

I can manage extracting the info for each line, word, letter and pass it to blender.

My question is:

Is there a way to have a text object containing multi text boxes with different colours, text-alignments, font sizes?

If not, I'm going to have to generate text objects. In this case:

Does anyone know of a way or a script to reproduce the layout (including text-align)? or would I have to write a script to generate 1 object per letter and then re-arrange them accordingly? I would have to re-create words, lines and then place them so it matches the alignment.

Here's a picture with what I'm trying to achieve, Thanks!:

[image]

Comment: Text size is per Text object. You can have multiple text boxes and multiple materials/colors on a per-character basis. You may want to go through the Blender Manual on [text object capabilities](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/texts/introduction.html)

Comment: how about generating svg from javascript and import this in blender instead?